# passing an array from controller to view in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following code in my Ruby Controller :

**mastertest_controller.rb**

```
def index

 ......

 @mastertest = connection.execute("select code_ver from mastertest")
 result_array = { sometihng }

 ......

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @mastertest}
  format.json { render :json => result_array}

 end
```

But it just allows me to access `@mastertest` in the view(`index.html.erb`). How do I pass the array to the view ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

instance variables in your controller are passed as instance variables in your view.

Controller:

```
@result_array = [something, second_something]
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @result_array.each do |item| %>
  <%= item %>
<% end %>
```